# How to find all named ranges in a workbook

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Here is some code that I am using so far:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
// Make the object visible.
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

I know the workbook opens.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 5):

The `Workbooks.Open()` function returns a workbook object which you need to store and it contains more objects with the workbook data. You should be able to get all this information from intellisense or you can find information on the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Here is an example script which will open a message box with the names of each of the named ranges in the workbook at path.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Application excelApp = new Application();
Workbook myWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
Names wbNames = myWorkbook.Names;
foreach (Name n in wbNames)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(n.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That gave me a big leg up. However I think you left out some text in your first line. Also I don't know if the "Forms" is correct .

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the missing object initialization on the first line. Also note that you can get rid of all the repetitive `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.` parts by adding `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks @SMStroble,
The solution works as expected! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the location of the nametag (called value):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names Names = wb.Names;
            foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name item in Names)
            {
                if(item.Name.Contains("cellexportcondition"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString() + " = " + item.Value.ToString());
                }               
            }
```

OR you can also get the cell values (if you want to do this in the workbook.beforeclose event you will need to reïnit the app and worksheet)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application tempexcellApp= wb.Application;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet tws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)tempexcellApp.Worksheets[1];

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Names Names = wb.Names;
            foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name item in Names)
            {
                if(item.Name.Contains("cellexportcondition"))
                {
                    string a = "";
                    if(tws.Range[item.Name].Value2 != null)
                    {
                     a  = item.Name + " " + tws.Range[item.Name].Value2.ToString();
                    }else a = item.Name + " empty cell ";
                    MessageBox.Show(a);
                }               
            }
```